# Set Timeout for Socket in Fortran and WS2_32

Tags: windows, sockets, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a client in Fortran (ifort) which connects to a sockets, sends some data and receives some data.
Because sometimes the connected server could halt or terminate I don't want to wait indefinitely for the response and set a timeout on the receiving end and handle the problem on my side.

I don't have any control over the server. The communication is blocking, no threads or anything.

I use 'WS2_32' for the socket / connection Handling and the communication works fine. The problem is setting the timeout.

I'm trying 'setsockopt' to set the Timeout

```
         ...
         status = WSAStartup(WINSOCK_V2_2, wsaInfo)
         ...
         connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
         ...

         status = setsockopt(connection,SOL_SOCKET,
     +                          SO_RCVTIMEO,Timeout,
     +                          sizeof(Timeout))

         ...
          status = connect(connection,
     +                       %REF(connectionInfo),
     +                       SIZEOF(connectionInfo))
```

For `Timeout` I tried different things. Using Integer(4) or Integer(DWORD) doesn't Compile. Using Character(4) does Compile and status returns 0 (success) but i don't get any timeout.

I tried with quite small values `10` or `'10'`, which should be milliseconds. But it always waits indefinitely.

Comment: Whaft kind of interface does it use? Is it provided by Intel?

Comment: I belive so. I declare "use ws2_32" at the start of the subroutine. Intel provides the Interface description.